# presto sql: date range for a query to be based on a start date + days from another table

Tags: sql, presto

i am trying to get the features used by users during trial, to do this i have two tables:

1. trial user data: has trial start date - end date, user id and other details
2. usage table - user id and usage information, usage_date, so if a user uses a feature, say product page, then the date the feature is used is recorded in this table.
   trial days = 8, so user is usually in a trial for 8 days.
   I am trying to get the feature usage for those 8 days from the feature usage table:

   ```
   WITH trial data AS
   (select user_id, .. 
   from trial_table
   where trial-start-date between '2023-01-10' AND '2023-01-27'
   )
   SELECT 
   user_id,
   ..
   FROM trial_users LEFT join feature usage on user_id = user_id
   ```

this is a rough query i have, i am a little confused on how to set the dates for the feature date table to pick up the data for 8 days trial period based on the trial_start_date. Users could start on any of the days between '2023-01-10' AND '2023-01-27' but we need their feature usage data for 8 days + the start date, wonder how to get this done. any help appreciated.

Here is the query i am using:

```
WITH trial data AS
(select user_id, .. 
from trial_table
where trial-start-date between '2023-01-10' AND '2023-01-27'
)
SELECT 
user_id,
..
FROM trial_users LEFT join feature usage on user_id = user_id
```

Comment: Please add sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

i think i got the answer, i have to add this as an and condition to the join: click_Date BETWEEN trial_start_date AND DATE_ADD('DAY',8, trial_start_date)